# Scanning a file and matching strings Java ( Looking for a better way )

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am creating a simple java program which scans through a file and looks for specific strings, i have it working to some degree but i am sure that there is a much more efficient and better way of doing it, i am using an IF contains method to compare for many different strings however i feel that it is a bad way of practicing and was wondering if anyone could give me an idea of what else i could try?

```
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

          readLine = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
          x = readLine.nextLine();
          numberOfLines++;  


            if (x.contains("a")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("A")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("e")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("E")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("i")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("I")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("o")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("O")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("u")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
            if (x.contains("U")) {
                numberOfConsonants++;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like so:

```
Set<String> consonants = new HashSet<>();
consonants.add("a");
consonants.add("e");
consonants.add("i");
consonants.add("o");
consonants.add("u");

while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

          readLine = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
          x = readLine.nextLine();
          numberOfLines++;  

          if(consonants.contains(x.toLowerCase())) { 
              consonants++;
          }
}
```

This will allow you to place the letters and match them at a later stage. Sets should provide you with a fairly quick way of checking if an item exists or not.

As a side note, you are matching vowels, not consonants (that might create confusion in your code).

Comment: yes thank you i i am looking for both i just got variable names mixed up thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about regular expressions (for example at the oracle tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ )

Regular expressions allow you to "match" a patterns against strings. 
And you can specify a pattern that matches all vowels "in one shoot"; thereby collapsing your cascade of if statements into a single one.

(and I guess you mean vowels, not consonants?)

Comment: yeah sorry i am looking for both consonants and vowells i just got the variable names mixed up haha thank you for your suggestion